# Use laptop to share WiFi?

Tags: wireless

What I'm trying to accomplish is having my laptop connected to a WiFi network, and then sharing the Internet from the laptop through another router. I already have a router with dd wrt installed, I just don't know how to set it up.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you will have a router that is connecting wirelessly to a laptop, and then you would like to have the connection from that laptop shared to another router that is connected via ethernet?

Comment: Yes I have my own router that I can connect to the laptop with an ethernet cord and I would like to use this router for broadcasting. So I basically want to be able to tether other devices to the Internet through this laptop.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is already connected to Internet then go to System Settings -> Network and then in the Wireless section, click on "Use as hotspot".

After the security notification, it will show you the network name and the wep key needed to connect to this network (those informations can be customized).

For more details, you can also check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point).

Comment: This does not seem to answer the use case of the OP, as he has access to a WiFi network and wants to share this WiFi network (probably over ethernet)

Comment: @Bruni Please read his (@Triton's) comment above. He clearly said that "I basically want to be able to tether other devices to the Internet through this laptop"